# Is Abstract Factory Pattern implemented correctly for given scenario....?

Tags: design-patterns

First thing... I am novice to pattern world, so correct me if wrong anywhere
Scenario:
There are multiple companies providing multiple products of diff size

so there are 3 entities i.e. Companies, Their Product and size of product

I have implement Abstract Pattern on this i.e. so that I will create instance of 
IProductFactory interface to get desired product...

Is below implementation of Abstract Factory Pattern correct ??? If not then please correct the approach 
+ 
Also tell me if any other pattern can be used for such scenario
Thanks in advance...

```
public enum Companies
{
    Samsung = 0,
    LG = 1,
    Philips = 2,
    Sony = 3
}

public enum Product
{
    PlasmaTv = 0,
    DVD = 1
}

public enum ProductSize
{
    FortyTwoInch,
    FiftyFiveInch
}

interface IProductFactory
{
    IPhilips GetPhilipsProduct();
    ISony GetSonyProduct();
}

interface ISony
{
    string CreateProducts(Product product, ProductSize size);
}
interface IPhilips
{
    string CreateProducts(Product product, ProductSize size);
}

class ProductFactory : IProductFactory
{
    public IPhilips GetPhilipsProduct()
    {
        return new Philips(); 
    }

    public ISony GetSonyProduct()
    {
        return new Sony();
    }
}

class Philips : IPhilips
{
    #region IPhilips Members

    public string CreateProducts(Product product, ProductSize size)
    {// I have ingnore size for now....
        string output = string.Empty;
        if (product == Product.PlasmaTv)
        {
            output = "Plasma TV Created !!!";
        }
        else if (product == Product.DVD)
        {

            output = "DVD Created !!!";
        }
        return output;
    }

    #endregion
}

class Sony : ISony
{// I have ingnore size for now....
    #region ISony Members
    public string CreateProducts(Product product, ProductSize size)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        if (product == Product.PlasmaTv)
        {
            output = "Plasma TV Created !!!";
        }
        else if (product == Product.DVD)
        {

            output = "DVD Created !!!";
        }
        return output;
    }
    #endregion
}



IProductFactory prodFactory = new ProductFactory();
IPhilips philipsObj = prodFactory.GetPhilipsProduct();
MessageBox.Show(philipsObj.CreateProducts(Product.DVD, ProductSize.FortyTwoInch));

or

//ISony sonyObj = prodFactory.GetSonyProduct();
//MessageBox.Show(sonyObj.CreateProducts(Product.DVD, ProductSize.FortyTwoInch));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it should rather look like this:

```
interface IProductFactory
{
    string CreateProducts(Product product, ProductSize size);
}

class SonyProductFactory : IProductFactory
{
    string CreateProducts(Product product, ProductSize size) { ... }
}
class PhilipsProductFactory : IProductFactory
{
    string CreateProducts(Product product, ProductSize size) { ... }
}

...
IProductFactory prodFactory = loadProductFactory();
MessageBox.Show(prodFactory.CreateProducts(Product.DVD, ProductSize.FortyTwoInch));
```

`loadProductFactory()` returns a Sony or Philips factory, maybe based on configuration, or application state. This functionality could be moved into a separate factory loader class as well, to make it more reusable.

**Update**: A trivial implementation could be

```
IProductFactory loadProductFactory() {
    String factoryName = System.getProperty("factory.name");
    if (factoryName.equals("Sony") {
        return new SonyProductFactory();
    } else {
        return new PhilipsProductFactory();
    }
}
```

A more robust version could load the concrete product factory classname from a config file, load the class, verify that it is an `IProductFactory`, then return an instance of it. This has the benefit that there are no more dependencies to any concrete product factory class, so adding/changing/removing factory implementations requires no recompilation of the sources, only a config file change.

Comment: Honestly.. I am not sure as how to provide defination for loadProductFactory(); .... could you please provide some more thoughts on that pls ?